# How do I get the "children" of "part of" property? / Accessing hierarchical structures

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I want to get all military operations that are *part of* (P361) WW2, I don't get, e.g., Case Blue, because it is only a *part of* the Soviet German War but not *part of* WW2, but the Soviet German War itself is *part of* WW2. So what do I need to do to the statement to get also all "children" of all ww2 campaigns like Case Blue and ideally also the subsequent battles of those campaigns?

Query:

```
SELECT ?label WHERE {
  ?subj wdt:P361 wd:Q362.
  ?subj (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q831663.
  ?subj rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")
}
```

EDIT - I think I found an improvement, but not really sure if is correct and it also feels a bit like a "hack", especially the distinct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?label WHERE {
  ?campaign wdt:P361 wd:Q362.
  ?campaign (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q198.
  ?battle wdt:P361*/wdt:P279* ?campaign.
  ?battle rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER((LANG(?label)) = "en")
}
```

Case Blue:
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q158287

German-Sovetic War:
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q189266

Comment: Why is it a hack? If you assume that "part of" is a transitive relation in your context, then property paths via `*` is indeed the correct way.

Comment: I can't imagine why `DISTINCT` would make it a hack, either.

Comment: guess I consider it a "hack", because it was more of an empirical/trial-and-error result than "yeah, I got it".